# Do I need to cleanup my event handlers when DOM changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, garbage-collection

If I make ajax requests that remove the body HTML and append new HTML, do I need to also remove any event handlers that were added to the previous HTML?

I noticed that if I don't, everything works fine. Does the browser free the memory and stuff? What if I do thousands of such ajax requests without  refreshing the browser? Will I get memory leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add jQuery event handlers :

- they will be cleaned if you use jQuery removing/replacing functions
- they won't be cleaned if you use direct DOM functions

On most function documentations, you have a comment similar to [this one](http://api.jquery.com/html/) :

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was
>   in that element is completely replaced by the new content.
>   Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event
>   handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the
>   new content.

If you're coherent, you'll have no memory leak, you don't have to manually remove data or event handlers. There's usually no problem in having a page kept open for days and issuing thousands of Ajax requests and changing the screen accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Clear answer and straight to the point :) Oh the page won't be open for days, I'm just trying to create a "live" administration area